# How do i make iis my main web server within parallels desktop whislt doing the development osx side?

Tags: asp.net, macos, parallels

I currently own an iMac but do allot of asp.net based development in Parallels Desktop.How do i make iis my main web server within parallels desktop whilst doing the development osx side?

I hope that makes sense

Comment: Don't quite understand, are you wanting to do ASP.NET development using OSX-only software or using Visual Studio?

Comment: It is .NET development using VS within parallels desktop on a mac, but the virtual OS is the main server instead of apache on the mac

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Decide to sell the mac, and went windows only